# actionscript3. enter_frame event on certain frames?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have only just started to learn a bit of actionscript/javascript.
I'm trying to apply a glow and blur filter to an instance of a sun. (I realise I could do this without actionscript, but the project requires some use of as3) Problem is the sun does not appear in every frame. Can an enter_frame event still be used?
Is there a much more simple way I could do this?

This is my code so far:

```
import flash.filters.GlowFilter;
import flash.filters.BlurFilter;
import flash.events.Event;

var sunglow:GlowFilter= new GlowFilter(0xffff00,0.8);
var sunblur:BlurFilter= new BlurFilter();
var f:int = 0;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,fl_EnterFrameHandler);
function fl_EnterFrameHandler(event:Event):void{
if (f > 29 && f < 350) { 
var random1 = Math.random()*2+40;
var random2 = Math.random()*2+8;
sunglow.blurX = random1;
sunglow.blurY = random1;
sunblur.blurX = random2;
sunblur.blurY = random2;
sunshine.filters = [sunglow,sunblur];
}
f++;
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `EnterFrame` event is a correct approach here, but checking the presence of `sunshine` on the scene is more flexible, than the frames numbers:

> if (f > 29 && f < 350) -> if (sunshine)

Whenever the sun appears on the scene, filters will be applied to it, even you make some changes in the timeline.